# is it possible to get the same result as line.rstrip('\n') for line in user_file.readlines()].index(login_username) while using open("file", "a+")

Tags: python

i am trying to make a simple log in and and sign up system with python (i am new to python and this is a small project for myself). for the sign up system to work i have to append to a text file so i can add the additional information for sign up but in the meantime i also need to let log in work too. By using

`[line.rstrip('\n') for line in user_file.readlines()].index(login_username)` i am trying to get the user's input of the username and then find the line where the username is (in the txt file) at and according to which line it is at it will check another text file which contains the password and see if at that line in has the password.

repeat: is there a way too get the same result as `[line.rstrip('\n') for line in user_file.readlines()].index(login_username)` while using `open("username", "a+)`

this is my code

```
login_password = None
login_username = None

log_right = False

signup_password = None
signup_username = None

# makes sure that password is correct
cl_pw = False

# makes sure when they sign up the username.txt isn't taken
taken_username = False

pw_file = open("passwor and username", "a+")
user_file = open("username.txt", "a+")
while log_right == False:


    log_sign = input("Do you want to Log In or Sign Up: ")

    if log_sign == "log in" or log_sign == "Log in" or log_sign == "Log In" or log_sign == "log In":

        print("loading...")
        time.sleep(0.4)

        while cl_pw == False:
            login_username = input("Username: ")
            login_password = input("Password: ")
            if login_username in open("username.txt").read():
                lines = int([line.rstrip('\n') for line in user_file.readlines()].index(login_username))
#i think there is something wrong beyond this line
                if pw_file.readlines()[lines] == login_password:
                    print("you have logged in")
                else:
                    print("You have entered the wrong password")
                    print(lines)

                cl_pw = True
                log_right = True

            elif login_username == "":
                print("you are not registered. Do you want to sign up?")

            else:
                print("you are not registered. Do you want to sign up?")


    elif log_sign == "Sign Up" or log_sign == "sign up" or log_sign == "Sign up" or log_sign == "sign Up":
        time.sleep(0.6)
        print("loading...")
        time.sleep(0.4)

        while taken_username == False:
            signup_username = input("Username: ")
            signup_password = input("Password: ")
            if signup_username in open("username.txt").read():
                print("The username.txt you chose have been take, please pick another username.txt")
            else:
                user_file.write("\n" + signup_username)
                pw_file.write("\n" + signup_password)
                print("Sign up SUCCESS")
                taken_username = True
        log_right = True
    else:
        print("Please enter either Log In or Sign Up")

pw_file.close()
user_file.close()
```

if there is anymore questions needed to be answered in order to get more information about this please feel free to ask and i will try to answer to my best. thank you

Comment: That title is so bad most people will not read through to the end of it. You'll bring more attention with concise titles.

Comment: yea as i said i am really new to all this and i am trying my best to make it clear. Do you have any advise i could shorten it or make it easier to read? i am also limited to 150 characters so i really don't know what to do.

Comment: Please read [mre]. It's best if you can reduce that to a minimal example including a minimal example of the data (your text files).

Comment: Tangent: Maybe you should refactor and open the file for reading when *logging in* and open the file for writing/appending when *signing up*. Additionally you should probably open the file as a context manager using `with` - https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the file directly and use `enumerate` to get the line number. This won't consume the whole file at once but stop at the first match (this also saves a temporary list being built in memory):

```py
next(i for i, line in enumerate(user_file) if line.rstrip('\n') == login_username)
```

Comment: @Jeez123 This means no matching user name was found. In your code it should give a `IndexError` then.

Comment: i am 100% sure that the username is inside of the text file because i put `if login_username in open("username.txt").read():` so it is 100% confirmed that it is there. there might be something in my code making it so it does not work properly but i am new to this so i don't know what it is.

Comment: hey i have just tested the same code in another python file and it works seems like there is something in my code making it wrong i really have no idea can you help?

Comment: @Jeez123 You should narrow down the problem and then ask a separate question if something still remains unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Reading between the lines, a user's password is on the same line in the password file as its line in the user file.  You can iterate over lines from each file in tandem using zip - this should relieve you of finding an index from one file and using it in the other.  Here is a toy example.

```
login_username = 'myname'
login_password = 'mypwd'
canlogin = False
with open("passwor and username") as pw_file, open("username.txt") as user_file:
    for name,pwd in zip(user_file,pw_file):
        if login_username == name.strip() and login_password == pwd.strip():
            canlogin = True
            break
if canlogin:
    print('login succesfull')
else:
    print('either uname or pwd are wrong')
```